# ruby: curses: Do not clear screen at end of program?

Tags: ruby, screen, ncurses, curses

I'm using the ruby curses package (ruby 2.1.5).

In certain cases, I'd like the screen *not* to be cleared at the end of my program, so that the final contents of **Curses.stdscr** are still showing on my terminal when the program exits.

I've tried leaving out the call to **Curses.close_screen**, but the terminal screen still gets cleared upon exit.

Is there any way to tell curses in ruby to not clear the screen when the program is terminating?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundled Ruby curses module lacks (many) curses functions such as [`reset_shell_mode`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-reset_prog_mode_-reset_shell_mode), which would be the usual way to do this:

> The **`reset_prog_mode`** and **`reset_shell_mode`** routines  restore
>   the  terminal  to *"program"* (in curses) or *"shell"* (out of
>   curses) state.  These are done automatically by [endwin(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html)
>   and,  after  an  **`endwin`**, by **`doupdate`**, so they normally are
>   not called.

Alternatively, you could use [MRuby](https://github.com/jbreeden/mruby-curses) (which provides the function).

In either case, exiting like this can leave your terminal's special keys set to [*application mode*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows).  The workaround for that would be to send an escape sequence (found in the terminal database as **`rmkx`**).

Comment: Actually, MRuby indeed looks like the best way to manage this. Comparing the list of functions in the bundled curses to the MRuby function list shows quite a few missing functions in the ruby curses bundle. I will start converting my programs to use MRuby, and I'll report back within a few days.

Comment: It turns out that I have been unable to get MRuby working on my Linux box. PDCurses will not easily compile, and it also has issues with the Linux ncurses. I could probably get the ncurses version working, eventually, with some refactoring of the MRuby code, but I don't need to do that work now. Doing what I suggested in my answer with the additional bit involving the rmkx escape sequence does the job for me, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: it turns out that if I exit my program with **exit!** instead of just **exit**, none of the screen resetting logic of curses gets invoked, and the latest contents of **stdscr** remain on my screen.

I also do the following before calling **Curses.init_screen** ...

```
require 'termios'
$orig_termios = Termios.tcgetattr($stdin)
```

... and I issue this command right before the **exit!** ...

```
Termios.tcsetattr($stdin, Termios::TCSANOW, $orig_termios)
```

(I want to accept this answer, but I can't do that for 2 more days. I will do so at that time).